# Protecting response data in WebApi (React, NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, validation

I am building a public web application where one of the features is a database of companies and their details. When my main components mount I pull all the companies records from my MongoDB database.

`/api/companies`

My approach is to obtain all the records from DB to my web app in React and then filter, sort and work on them without asking DB anymore.

So the query returns 800+ objects which is ok but it gives to my competition a clear DB screen with all the companies details in JSON which they can simply copy and paste and then process. It took me a lot of time to create this database.

I am wondering what would be the best approach to protect them?

Comment: if you dont want the user to be able to access the data dont send it back from the server...

Comment: You can encrypt your data and decrypt it in your app. This would add some "protection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice regarding encrypting and decrypting the certain parts and it seems to work best. I am using `crypto-json` library for Node and encode certain properties like company name and contact details.

The encrypted record grows big if I chose to encrypt everything but the partial encoding works fine too.